# Conditional filtering for Tableau worksheets using Tabcmd

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have a dashboard which has two worksheets in it. I have a filter that is applied to only one of the two sheets. It works perfectly when I upload it on the Tableau server. However, when I use tabcmd to get pdf of the dashboard by just iterating over that one filter, it applies to both the sheets within the dashboard.
I have already set that filter to apply to the desired worksheet. 
How can I solve this issue?

I tried creating a copy of the same filter and applying to the sheet I don't want it to affect. I also did add context to the original filter and then tried to run it through tabcmd. Both options didn't seem to work.

Here is my code: The '`&Location%20Group=' + LocGroup.replace(' ','%20')` filter is getting applied to both sheets instead of 1
Also, I am running tabcmd in python

```
for LocGroup in LocationGroup:
    BatchString = 'tabcmd get "' + View + Dashboard + SnapType + SnapSize + '&Year=' + Year + '&Month=' + Month + '&Location%20Group=' + LocGroup.replace(' ','%20') + '" -f "' + SnapFolder + '\\' + Year + '_' + Month + '_' + LocGroup + SnapType + '"\n'
    print(BatchString)
    GetSnaps(BatchString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fixed (LOD) calculations in the sheet where you don't want the filter to be applied.

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm#FIXED

Comment: Link only answers are not considered good practice. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: The explanation is quite brief, but mentions the relevant concept. I let this pass as not link-only.